# ¿Cómo obtener la respuesta de un ws, cuando el código de respuesta HTTP es diferente a 200?

Tags: ios, swift2

Soy nuevo en iOS. Estoy aprendiendo Swift2. Tengo un servicio RESTful que al momento de ocurrir un error (4XX) necesito acceder a un objeto JSON que responde el ws para mostrar un feedback al usuario con un mensaje coherente con lo sucedido. 
Actualmente estoy usando Alamofire 2.0 para conectarme y EVReflection para serializar las respuestas del servidor.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Actualmente, al recibir una respuesta HTTP 200, en el completion handler recibo de la siguiente forma los objetos:

```
(request, response, data) in
     if response?.statusCode==200{
         if(data.isSuccess){
             onResponse(response: (data.value)!,error:nil)
         }                    
     }
```

Cuando la respuesta es diferente de 200, `data.value` viene nulo, siendo que el servidor igual respondió un objeto indicando los motivos del error. Necesito obtener ese objeto.

Comment: por favor revisa tu pregunta pues no me queda claro que es lo necesitas.

Comment: @JuanK actualicé la pregunta con mayores detalles. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Mirando un poco la documentación, he visto que hay un método como este:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .response { request, response, data, error in
             print(request)
             print(response)
             print(data)
             print(error)
         }
```

Y este método te devuelve también el objeto `error` de tipo `NSError`. Lo que tendrías que hacer es usar este método y en el bloque de respuesta hacer algo así:

```
if error != nil {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    onResponse(response: nil, error:error)
}
else {
    if response?.statusCode == 200 {
        if (data.isSuccess) {
            onResponse(response: (data.value)!, error:nil)
        }                    
    }
}
```

Obviamente con tu propia adaptación para mostrar los errores o lo que te haga falta hacer.